# Why is the list data not displayed in the list box?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I started programming a few days ago and I am stuck trying to figure out why my code is not working. Would highly appreciate any help!

Here is my code:

```
...

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<String> names = new List<String>();

        BindingSource namesBindingSource = new BindingSource();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        
            if (CmdClockInOut.Text == "XYZ") 
            {
                names.Add("123");
            }
        } 
         private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            namesBindingSource.DataSource = names;

            listBox1.DataSource = namesBindingSource;
        }
         
    }
```

The data are only displayed in the listbox when `names.Add("123");` is entered in the public Form1():

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        namesBindingSource.DataSource = names;

        listBox1.DataSource = namesBindingSource;

        names.Add("123");

    }
```

Comment: Try using `ObservableCollection<T>`, as this implements the events that need to fire that should cause the UI to update. Note that I have little experience with WinForms.

Comment: Try a `BindingList` instead.  The generic `List` doesn't tell anything the list has changed.

Comment: @LarsTech BindingList solved my problem, thank you so much for your prompt reply :) However, I have read that there are some disadvantages. Is there a more efficient way to achieve what I am trying to achieve? What is the proper way of adding items to a list box?

Comment: You would have to define "efficient"?  The code worked, so I would continue down that path.

Comment: Note that the BindingSource maintains a BindingList internally. You can just add items to the BindingSource's `List` to both update your source List and the ListBox -- Since the source of data is just a `List<string>`, you don't have so many *more efficient* tools or procedures for this

Comment: I see, thank you guys :)

Comment: Alternatively, manually set the datasource again each time the list changes.